# How to put alert when the element is overflowing in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am creating dynamic navigation tabs.
I have Home tab(non-closable) whose content has some links. Each links open in a new tab. When the tab occupies all the space available( 900px in my usecase) and still clicks on link for new tab, user should get alert message
Note: Tabs are of dynamic length.

```
"Close old tabs to open new tabs."
```

Is there a way to find if the opening tab will overflow?

```
<div class="mytabs">
    <ul class="nav-tabs" style="width: 900px; background-color: gray;" >
        <li ng-class="{'active': activeTab === tab.title}"
            ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <a  ng-click="onSelectTab(tab.title)">{{tab.title}}</a>
            <span ng-show="tab.isClosable" ng-click="onClose(tab.title)">
                   <i class="left fa fa-times-circle closeButton" ></i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="bd-bottom clearfix"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row mytabs">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 tab-content">
            <div ng-transclude class="mytabs"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please guide..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such a function but you can try to do it with some simple maths : 
Let's say a tab is 50px;

```
If (number_of_tab * 50 > 900)
alert("Close old tabs to open new tabs.");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Each tab is of dynamic size. I am not able to get the element width before it populates on the screen. So, I thought overflow might help. Please suggest if u have any other idea.

Comment: Can't you create a global variable size, add the tab size each time the user opens a new tab and check if the variable is bigger or smaller then 900px ?

Comment: I tried it but the value is not getting value till the element is formed. Once the element is formed, the tab is visible. :(

Comment: can you try to get value after the element is formet with a settimeout ?
but it's a dirty method x)

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should know the width of each tab. Is it fixed width? Then max number of tabs is `maxTabs = 900 / width`, and then just keep track of number of opened tabs.

If tabs width may vary, then you should keep track of total *width* of all the tabs. After opening new tab, add its width to total.

In both cases, don't forget to subtract after closing.